# Using LIKE in a parameter to distinguish between teams

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that I would like to parametise so that users can pick between seeing stats for a dedicated team, regular users or both. If I was manually distinguishing in my SQL I would use

> Where [User Name] like ('%Dedicated')

for the dedicated team and

> Where [User Name] NOT like ('%Dedicated')

for the regular users (dedicated team members always have Dedicated tagged onto the end of their user name)

I'm not sure of the syntax for turning those SQL where clauses into SSRS parameter expressions. I tried

> = Like ('%Dedicated')

for one parameter and

> =Not Like ('%Dedicated')

for the other with

> = Like ('%')

for both

and

> Where [User name] @Team

in my SQL

but it threw up an error "Expression expected" so I must have gotten the syntax wrong. Can anyone advise? I would normally put the LIKE directly into the SQL but in this case it sometimes needs to be like and sometime not like depending on the option chosen.

Edited to add SQL :

```
 WITH [data] as

(
SELECT 

iif([Agent Name] like '%Robert Dyas', 1, 0) as [Dedicated]

,convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date], 
[Client Name],
[Account],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call','Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [Calls Offered],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [Ring Offs],
sum(iif([Ring (secs)] <= 20 AND [Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Answered in 20 Secs],
sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),[Ring (secs)],NULL)) as [Total Ring Time],
sum([connected (secs)]) as [Total Connected Time],
sum(iif([Ring (secs)] > 5 AND [Type] in ('Caller rang off','Caller rang off during divert','No suitable operator logged on'),1,0)) as [CRO After 5 Secs],
avg(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),[Ring (secs)],null)) as 'Avg Time to Answer',

avg(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),[Connected (secs)],null)) as 'Avg Call Time'


 ,sum(iif(rtrim([rhoutcome]) = 'MESSAGE',1,0)) AS [Total Messages]

  FROM ipr.dbo.InboundCallsView IC left JOIN [iAnalyse].[dbo].[iAnalyse3_iResultsHeaderXML] ires ON ic.[Reference]   = ires.[rhcallref]


  WHERE [account] = '106844'


  AND Dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]) between '2017-05-29' AND '2017-05-31'





  group BY iif([Agent Name] like '%Robert Dyas', 1, 0), format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),[client name],[account]

)

select 
    *
from [data] as [d]
where d.Dedicated = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Different approach**

Instead of the `iif()` from below, try using

`where ([Agent Name] like '%' + (@Parameter) or (@Parameter) is null)`

You can use a small dataset to create the values for your parameter:

```
select 
    null as [Value],
    'All' as [Label]

union all

select 
    'Dedicated' as [Value],
    'Dedicated' as [Label]

union all

select
    '' as [Value],
    'Not Dedicated' as [Label]
```

Set your parameter up in SSRS to allow null value, be of type Text, and not to accept multiple values. Use this dataset to give the values/labels for the parameter.

Hopefully this one runs a bit faster!

---

In your SQL you could do something like..

```
iif(UserName like '%Dedicated', 1, 0) as [Dedicated]
```

(I use the shorthand `iif()` rather than a `case` for simplicity)

Then you can filter to..

`where Dedicated in (@Parameter)`

Your parameter can then have multiple defined values -

- Dedicated = 1
- Not Dedicated = 0

Allow the user to select multiple values.

You may have to put your SQL into a CTE or derived table to be able to use the `[Dedicated]` field you created.

This is a mock up of how I would do this in a CTE:

```
with [data] as
(
    select 
        *,
        iif(t.UserName like '%Dedicated', 1, 0) as [Dedicated]
    from dbo.[Table] as [t]
)
select 
    *
from [data] as [d]
where d.Dedicated in (@Parameter)
```

Version of how I would approach your SQL:

```
with [data] as
(
    select 
        iif([Agent Name] like '%Robert Dyas', 1, 0) as [Dedicated],
        convert(date, format(Dateadd(hour, 1, [Start Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date], 
        [Client Name],
        [Account],
        iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call', 'Caller rang off', 'Caller rang off during divert', 'No suitable operator logged on'), 1, 0) as [Calls Offered],
        iif([Type] = 'Normal operator call', 1, 0) as [Calls Answered],
        iif([Type] in ('Caller rang off', 'Caller rang off during divert', 'No suitable operator logged on'), 1, 0) as [Ring Offs],
        iif([Ring (secs)] <= 20 and [Type] = 'Normal operator call', 1, 0) as [Answered in 20 Secs],
        iif([Type] = 'Normal operator call', [Ring (secs)], null) as [Total Ring Time],
        [connected (secs)] as [Total Connected Time],
        iif([Ring (secs)] > 5 and [Type] in ('Caller rang off', 'Caller rang off during divert', 'No suitable operator logged on'), 1, 0) as [CRO After 5 Secs],
        iif([Type] = 'Normal operator call', [Ring (secs)], null) as [Avg Time to Answer],
        iif([Type] = 'Normal operator call' ,[Connected (secs)], null) as [Avg Call Time],
        iif(rtrim([rhoutcome]) = 'MESSAGE',1,0) as [Total Messages]
    from ipr.dbo.InboundCallsView as [IC] 
        left join [iAnalyse].[dbo].[iAnalyse3_iResultsHeaderXML] as [ires] on ic.[Reference] = ires.[rhcallref]
    where [account] = '106844'
        and Dateadd(hour, 1, [Start Time]) between '2017-05-29' and '2017-05-31'
)
select 
    d.[Date],
    d.[Client Name],
    d.Account,
    sum(d.[Calls Offered]) as [Calls Offered],
    sum(d.[Calls Answered]) as [Calls Answered],
    sum(d.[Ring Offs]) as [Ring Offs],
    sum(d.[Answered in 20 Secs]) as [Answered in 20 Secs],
    sum(d.[Total Ring Time]) as [Total Ring Time],
    sum(d.[Total Connected Time]) as [Total Connected Time],
    sum(d.[CRO After 5 Secs]) as [CRO After 5 Secs],
    avg(d.[Avg Time to Answer]) as [Avg Time to Answer],
    avg(d.[Avg Call Time]) as [Avg Call Time],
    sum(d.[Total Messages]) as [Total Messages]
from [data] as [d]
where d.Dedicated = 1
group by 
    d.[Date],
    d.[Client Name],
    d.Account
```

Comment: Stangely when I add this condition it make the processing time insanely long. the iif(UserName like '%Dedicated', 1, 0) as [Dedicated] part works perfectly and runs in 5 seconds but if I add where iif(UserName like '%Dedicated', 1, 0) = 1 or wrap the whole thing in a 2nd select and try select * from ... where [dedicated] = 1 then it just runs and runs for an hour or more any idea why?

Comment: Added mock up to answer to explain the CTE element. Does yours look like that?

Comment: IT didn't at first but I tried it your way and it is still taking far far to long to run (had to cancel the execution) whereas just running what's inside the parentheses takes literally 5 seconds.

Comment: Can you share your SQL?

Comment: added to question. I left it out originally because I figured this could be an SSRS answer

Comment: Added how I would approach your script

Comment: Again it ran in 6 seconds without the where clause and 22 minutes 38 seconds with the where clause.

Comment: What indexing is on the AgentName column?

Comment: I'm not sure. I only have SELECT/view access to the database. To my knowledge I can't create or view the indices.

Comment: Edited with another option